# How to deploy NodeJs, Socket application on Heroku without any error?

Tags: node.js, express, websocket, socket.io

I have developed nodejs, socketIO based real time chat application. I have deployed on heroku. Build was successful. After 30-60 seconds, this app will crash every time.

```
019-11-12T19:39:57.319082+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=LjT06AikcmD9YNWMAAAA" host=ichatbd.herokuapp.com request_id=9e763230-a0c9-4dde-a147-f15ca50f7d67 fwd="103.218.24.238" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=21766ms status=101 bytes=183 protocol=https
2019-11-12T19:39:57.327674+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=_RnJVJZCLbuNcLBsAAAC" host=ichatbd.herokuapp.com request_id=7d6c1d10-9968-4b72-ac90-5eb7405ec9bd fwd="103.218.24.238" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=18554ms status=101 bytes=175 protocol=https
2019-11-12T19:39:57.382419+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2019-11-12T19:39:57.333853+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=g04ocLYoRLBqkwfTAAAB" host=ichatbd.herokuapp.com request_id=e8f312d2-e337-44ef-88a7-1c255f98a2f4 fwd="175.41.44.170" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=21288ms status=101 bytes=175 protocol=https
2019-11-12T19:39:58.398679+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/styles/style.css" host=ichatbd.herokuapp.com request_id=945c9699-1b14-4be0-901e-879dd369e91f fwd="103.218.24.238" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-11-12T19:39:58.954315+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MvX8Jki" host=ichatbd.herokuapp.com request_id=826c4735-8fd3-4b6f-9f79-f21ef12c0825 fwd="103.218.24.238" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Cant identify, whats the problem is. After using google, changed on port setup. I have added some code where i just implemented node server.

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 4000);

const server = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
const port = app.get('port');
```

So, can anybody help me to identify & solve this problem.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you can share us file where you are implementing io.connect.

I believe that you have a bug in somewhere of your code. also you can share us all logs of heroku with heroku cli you can see them eg. heroku logs app xxxxxx(nameapp in heroku)

Comment: Got my error on heroku logs. Thanks. Theres an error disconnect

Comment: nice!! I supposed that.